# html5 video delay while the source is fully downloaded

Tags: javascript, ios, video

I prefetch the whole video using a AJAX request, and use `createObjectURL` to create a local url for the video src.

When I called the `play` function, the video will play with a delay about 200ms in iOS devices.(android phone will play immediately)

What causes the delay? How to eliminate it?